# extract file permissions for files and folders to a file

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions

Is there some way I can get the file permissions for a folder or a file extracted to a file with some command in windows?

for instance:

```
dir ??? > permissions.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have at least windows 2003 sp2, then you can use [icacls.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919240):

```
icacls.exe [file|folder] > file.txt
```

you enter file or folder without the brackets, in case it is not clear enough. If you have something older, then you can use [setacl](http://helgeklein.com/), which is a wonderful little tool, but a bit complicated to get started with.

Comment: interesting. I found a flag "/save" which formats it very wierd. Do you know how to interpret that information? I got something like this:  `D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;ID;0x1301bf;;;AU)`

Comment: that is used to save and restore acls. No idea how to interpret it. If you just need to see the permissions on the cli, do not use any switch, just use the file or folder as only argument.

Answer (score 1):

[`secaudit`/`ntfs-3g.secaudit`](http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/secaudit.html) can extract the ACLs from a filesystem object.

Comment: I guess I'll have to download that. Is there some built-in way?

Comment: Dunno. I don't use Windows much.

Comment: hehe :) is it possible with a unix command (for reference)?

Comment: That would be `ntfs-3g.secaudit`.